# Rails: alternatives to using nested loops to find match in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

There has to be a better way to do this.  My `Favorite` model belongs to `User` while `Applicant` belongs to both `Gig` and `User`.  I am trying to efficiently determine whether a user has applied for `Gig` that was favorited (`<% if @application.present? %>`).

I tried chaining the collection by using something like `@favorites.each.gig` to no avail.  While the below index action for `Favorites` seems to work, it's really verbose and inefficient.  What is a more succinct way of doing this?

```
def index
  @favorites = Favorite.where(:candidate_id => current_candidate)
  @applications = Applicant.where(:candidate_id => current_candidate)

  @favorites.each do |favorite|
    @applications.each do |application|
      if favorite.gig.id == application.id
       @application = application
      end
    end
  end
end

class User
  has_many :applicants
  has_many :gigs, :through => :applicants
  has_many :favorites
end

class Favorite < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :candidate
 belongs_to :gig
end

class Applicant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gig
  belongs_to :candidate
end

class Candidate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :applicants
  has_many :gigs, :through => :applicants
  has_many :favorites
end

class Gig < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employer
  has_many :applicants
  has_many :favorites
  has_many :users, :through => :applicants
end
```

Comment: Can you show your model definitions with the "has" or "belongs_to" relations for everything involved? It would make it easier to visualize. You should be able to use a join to find what you want.

Comment: Also if your code is on Github and can be pulled it makes it easy for people to look at it and test answers. It may be that you want something like `has_many :through'. Maybe something like "Applicant has many Favorites through User"? I don't quite understand your data model with the small amount of info you've given.

Comment: Sure, I added the relevant sections from the models.

Comment: Can you try this in the console?: `Favorite.joins(:applicants).where("candidate_id = ?", current_candidate)` and report back what you get?

Comment: I got  `Association named 'applicants' was not found on Favorite`, so I added `has_one :applicant, :through => :gig` to the Favorite model since users may only apply once. This led me to: `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'applicants' was not found on 'Favorite'`.  Just for kicks, I tried changing it to has_many applicants through jobs and got: `Could not find the association :jobs in model Favorite`.

Answer (score 0):

For lack of a better answer, here's my idea:

--

**User**

Your user model should be structured as such (I just highlighted `foreign keys`, which I imagine you'd have anyway):

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :applicants
    has_many :gigs, :through => :applicants, foreign_key: "candidate_id"
    has_many :favorites, foreign_key: "candidate_id"
end
```

This means you'll be able to call:

```
current_candidate.favorites
current_candidate.applicants
```

This will remove the need for your `@applications` and `@favorites` queries

--

**Favorite**

You basically want to return a `boolean` of whether `applicant` is part of the `favorite` model or not. In essence, for each `favorite` the `candidate` has made, you'll be able to check if it's got an application

I would do this by setting an instance method on your `favorites` method using an [ActiveRecord Association Extension](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions), like so:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :favorites do
        def applied?
            self.applicant.exists? proxy_association.owner.gig.id
        end
    end
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
<%= for favorite in current_candidate.favorites do %>
    <%= if favorite.applied? %>
<% end %>
```

This is untested & highly speculative. I hope it gives you some ideas, though!

Comment: Did you mean to write the `applied` method on `Favorite` instead of `User`?  I got a method missing error for applied when calling on favorite.  Placing it in the `Favorite` model yielded a method missing error for the proxy association.